# font-awesome CSS in button

Tags: css, button, font-awesome, outline

I am having trouble deleting the outline of the button in CSS. I have to put the font awesome icon in button, so that it is accessible for screen . But I couldn't delete the outline of the button using outline:none or outline:0 in CSS.

```
  <button class="fa fa-calculator" aria-label="calculator"></button>
```

Comment: Show us the complete css please (Just the relevant part of course)

Comment: probably you didn't added the the `button:focus,button:active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by outline you mean border??  Since both have different meaning in CSS it's easy to get confused.

Den use

```
<button class="fa fa-calculator" style="border:none">
```

Or use this
     .Fa.fa-calculator{Border:none;}

& If you are specifically talking about outline den you ll have to share your CSS file mate!!:)